# Import PST file to specific mailbox with a Account with Full Access rights

Tags: outlook-redemption, pst

I am working on a command line tools which can Import PST file to specific mailbox (or any mailbox) with an Account with Full Access rights, What is the best way to archive this?

Redemption [Redemption DLL](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm), could be an option, is there any code example to do the import pst?

I know there is PowerShell function: New-MailboxImportRequest, first it require Exchange Powershell module, by using the powershell, I lost control,  don't know when the import is finished and if there is any error.

Really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Where is your code running? Is it running on a machine where Outlook is installed and there is a profile that connects to the mailbox in question?

Comment: yes, I can running the code on a machine and have Outlook installed and there is a profile that connects to the mailbox

Comment: You can create an instance of the RDOSession object, call RDOSession.Logon, then call RDOSession.Stores.AddPstStore (returns RDOPstStore object), You can then copy messages and folders (starting with RDOStore.UPMRootFolder) to the primary mailbox store in the profile.